# Printing the status of instance in Load Balancer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb

I want to print the status of the instance attached to load balancer.(InService/OutOfService).
How can I do that using Boto3. I have attached Screenshot to specify what I need to print.
Thanks In advance.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[describe_instance_health](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elb.html#ElasticLoadBalancing.Client.describe_instance_health) - Describes the state of the specified instances with respect to the specified load balancer

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("elb")
response = client.describe_instance_health(LoadBalancerName='testname')
for instance in response['InstanceStates']:
    print(instance['InstanceId'],instance['State'])
```